# SonarQube analysis java and net together

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonar-maven-plugin

I have a problem.
I need to analyze these two languages along with sonarQube 5.6, any idea how of to do it?

I have install maven and MSBuild SonarRunner but  I never made them run together

Comment: what did you try ? what did not work ?

Comment: Try to run a analysis from jenkins with the same Key, in an application that is made in .Net and JAVA, but first execute in NET and extracts a result.  And then run the java and step the previous result.

Comment: Same problem here with a legacy code. In the same repo we have Java and .Net in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you managed to combine to opposing tech stack in a project.

1. I guess you are talking about 2 projects analysis in same sonar instance.
   In this case use `sonar.language=java` to enforce analysis of one language.
2. If you are talking about 1 project using two stack that can work together, don't specify `sonar.language` Sonar analyser will deduct language to analyse based on plugins you have installed.
3. If 1 project but analysis are to be done seperately override the key and name of project to distinguish them. You can override by passing command line arguments

   -Dsonar.projectKey=ASDF-Java